# How to Place div elements next to each other?

Tags: html, css, jsp, layout, frontend

I am a beginner in CSS. In a JSP page, I have two divs that are under each other. Each div carries a field, button, and a table. I need to place the fields, tables, and buttons, next to each other instead of under each other. Below is my JSP for the 2 divs. How to achieve what i want?

First div:

```
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><b><spring:message code="supportive.criterea.section.label"/></b></div>
            <div class="panel-body ">

                <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-xs-12 float2">
                  <c:forEach items="${serviceFields}" var="serviceField">
                     <c:if test="${serviceField.columnName == 'v38'}">
                         <label for="criterea"> 
                              <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${i18n.language == 'en' }">${serviceField.labelEn}</c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>${serviceField.labelAr}</c:otherwise>
                              </c:choose>
                                    <c:if test="${serviceField.isRequired == 1}">
                                        <span class="required">&nbsp;</span>
                                    </c:if> 
                               </label>
                         <input type="text" value="${requestDetails.v38}"                       
                            class="form-control input-sm <c:if test="${serviceField.isRequired == 1 && step.isStart == 1}"> mandatory</c:if>"  
                            name="v38" id="criterea" <c:if test="${step != null && step.isStart != 1}"> disabled</c:if> />
                     </c:if>
                  </c:forEach>
              </div>


              <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 float2" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                        <label for="add">&nbsp;</label>
                        <label class="btn-is">
                            <img class="docIcon" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/icons/buttons/add-request.png" />&nbsp;<spring:message code="addToList.label"/>
                            <input type="button" id="add_criterea" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 col-md-6" <c:if test="${step != null && step.isStart != 1}"> disabled</c:if> style="display: none;"/>
                        </label>
             </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-12 float2" id="jobSuccessionListDiv">
                <jsp:include page="../../common/career-replacement-list.jsp"/>
            </div>



            </div>
            </div>
```

Second div

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><b><spring:message code="required.tasks.label"/></b></div>
    <div class="panel-body">


      <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-xs-12 float2">
          <c:forEach items="${serviceFields}" var="serviceField">
             <c:if test="${serviceField.columnName == 'v39'}">
                 <label for="tasks"> 
                      <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${i18n.language == 'en' }">${serviceField.labelEn}</c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>${serviceField.labelAr}</c:otherwise>
                      </c:choose>
                            <c:if test="${serviceField.isRequired == 1}">
                                <span class="required">&nbsp;</span>
                            </c:if> 
                       </label>
                 <input type="text" value="${requestDetails.v39}"                       
                    class="form-control input-sm <c:if test="${serviceField.isRequired == 1 && step.isStart == 1}"> mandatory</c:if>"  
                    name="v39" id="tasks" <c:if test="${step != null && step.isStart != 1}"> disabled</c:if> />
             </c:if>
          </c:forEach>
      </div> 


      <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 float2" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                <label for="add">&nbsp;</label>
                <label class="btn-is">
                    <img class="docIcon" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/icons/buttons/add-request.png" />&nbsp;<spring:message code="addToList.label"/>
                    <input type="button" id="add_task" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 col-md-6" <c:if test="${step != null && step.isStart != 1}"> disabled</c:if> style="display: none;"/>
                </label>
     </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12" id="jobSuccessionListDiv_1">
        <jsp:include page="../../common/career-replacement-list-1.jsp"/>
    </div>



    </div>      

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a container div, in which both of your div's are located. This div needs to be of `display:flex` and `flex-direction:row`:

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row">
<div id="firstdiv"></div>
<div id="seconddiv"></div>
</div>
```

The other solution would be, to add `display:inline-block` to both of your div's

Comment: Thanks for your help. they are next to each other now but with different heights and the fields are a bit missed up. Can you suggest how to place them properly? Thanks. Please check the capture of how they look now in my question. I updated it.

Comment: That probably is, because your width is a little bit to small to align them at full size: I was missing, that you are using bootstrap. Try using the `row` class on the container instead of using the two css properties. If you want them to have the same width, use the `col-6` class on both.

Comment: Thanks. Not same width, the width is ok. I want them same Height.

Comment: Ok. Try applying `align-items:stretch` as a style on your container

Comment: I tried align-items:stretch in multiple divs including the first inner one, but didn't work. Maybe what you suggested earlier about the width will help making the height ok because it seems to me there is a width issue as the first div is wider than second, but unfortunately, I couldn't do what you suggested about row or col-6 because I don't know in which container I should do that, and how to use the row class, can you update your question with an example or which div I should update, if possible, please? Thanks again

Comment: Align-items:stretch was meant to be used on the same div, where you placed "display:flex;" and "flex-direction:row" before. Did you try that? And the col-6 class has to be used on both of your divs, which are directly within the div having these 2 properties, mentioned before. I will update my answer later, when i am at my pc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It worked. I just needed to do additional properties like width:50% for each inner div of the 2 divs, and some button width enlarging using col-3 instead of col-2 to display them properly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="d-flex">
   <div class="innerDiv"></div>
   <div class="innerDiv"></div>
</div>
<style>
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}`
.innerDiv {
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right:15px;
}

</style>
```